# In a knockout tournament of $64$ players, what's the probability that P1 loses to P2 and P2 becomes the eventual champion?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$64$ players play in a knockout chess tournament assuming all the players are of equal strength the probability that $P_1$ loses to $P_2$ and $P_2$ becomes the eventual champion.

My try:

For any one to become the champion, the probability is $1/64$. But, we know that $P_2$ plays all $6$ matches, so he needs to play against $P_1$ in any of those $7$ games. I have no clue how to build on this.

The answer is $1/672$

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have already figured out, the probability of $P_2$ winning is $1/64$. And that if $P_2$ wins, he/she must play $6$ matches.

All you have to figure out is the probability of $P_2$ playing $P_1$ in one of those $6$ matches.$^*$

And then you multiply these $2$ probabilities.

$^*$Hint - Consider the number of ways to pick $P_2$'s six opponents. In one there's no restriction. In another $P_1$ must be there.

Comment: So the probability of the second part will be simply 62C5/63C6...

Comment: I don't think my question would qualify as a good question for this site

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct. And no, you shouldn't think your questions won't qualify as good here. It's just that you should include what you have tried and where you are stuck. More specific you are, the better it is. The problem is that far too many people try to treat MSE as a forum to get their homework questions solved. That's not how it works.